# Grails command that extends another command bug

Tags: java, oop, grails, command, extend

I'm having a problem with Commands in Grails when I extends one generic Command to reuse it's custom validator.

When I clean the grails project, it loses the reference to the extended custom validator. I need to cause a syntax error in CommandA with the project running and undo that error so it compiles back the command.

file: /src/groovy/app/commands/ImageCommand.groovy

```
class ImageCommand {
    static imageValidator = { value, command ->
        ... DO SOMETHING ...
    }
}
```

file: /src/groovy/app/commands/CommandA.groovy

```
class CommandA extends ImageCommand {
    def file
    static constraints = {
        file nullable: true, blank: true, validator: imageValidator
    }
}
```

To cause the error I just erase a part of the CommandA:

```
class CommandA extends ImageCommand {
    def file
    static constraints = {
        file nullable: true, blank: 
    }
}
```

And undo it to force recompile:

```
class CommandA extends ImageCommand {
    def file
    static constraints = {
        file nullable: true, blank: true, validator: imageValidator
    }
}
```

What should I do? I can't move my CommandA to the Controller file because I use it in many places.

*Using Grails 2.2.2

Comment: It should work. Can you post the stacktrace of your error?

Comment: There is no error. CommandA just ignores the validator as it was not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to move your validator to separate class in `src\groovy` like this:

```
class PhoneNumberConstraint extends AbstractConstraint {
    private static final String NAME = "phoneNumber";
    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE_CODE = "default.phoneNumber.invalid.message";

    @Override
    protected void processValidate(Object target, Object propertyValue, Errors errors) {
        if (!isPhoneNumber(target, propertyValue)) {
            Object[] args = [constraintPropertyName, constraintOwningClass, propertyValue]
            rejectValue(target, errors, DEFAULT_MESSAGE_CODE, DEFAULT_MESSAGE_CODE, args);
        }
    }

    private boolean isPhoneNumber(Object target, Object propertyValue) {
        if(propertyValue instanceof String && ((String)propertyValue).isNumber() &&
                (((String)propertyValue).length() == 13 || ((String)propertyValue).length() == 11)) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }


    @Override
    boolean supports(Class type) {
        return type != null && String.class.isAssignableFrom(type)
    }

    @Override
    String getName() {
        return NAME
    }
}
```

Then register your validator in `resources.groovy` like this:

```
beans = {
    ConstrainedProperty.registerNewConstraint(PhoneNumberConstraint.NAME, PhoneNumberConstraint.class);
}
```

It works for me flawlessly with commands.

Comment: I still can't make it work for me.  ERROR validation.ConstrainedProperty  - Exception thrown instantiating constraint [uploadImage] to class [class me.emotion.commands.profile.GodParentsAddCommand]
Message: Class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty can not access a member of class me.emotion.constraints.ImageConstraint with modifiers ""

Comment: Make sure all methods are public in ImageConstraint.